# C# integrate square form into existing form

Tags: square

I'm trying to integrate SquareUp into an existing MVC website. The documentation https://docs.connect.squareup.com/payments/sqpaymentform/setup, step 2, has a HTML form tag with the id="nonce-form".

Our existing HTML form tag has lots of various inputs in addition to the credit card details. Short of separating the credit card input into its own form, is there anyway to make one "master" form work?

Answer (score 0):

The form can be named whatever you want (the only other reference to "nonce-form" in the example is used to submit the form), so you add just the inputs to your existing form. You just need to make sure that whatever class your inputs have match the `SqPaymentForm.js` (inside of the `SqPaymentForm` object). For example in your `SqPaymentForm.js`:

```
// Initialize the credit card placeholders
  cardNumber: {
    elementId: 'sq-card-number',
    placeholder: '•••• •••• •••• ••••'
  },
```

And in the form you would have:

```
<div id="sq-card-number"></div>
```